# How can I include a D3 (Scatterplot) Chart inside a SAPUI5 Control

Tags: d3.js, charts, scatter-plot, sapui5

I'm trying to implement a scatter plot chart chart inside an SAPUI5 application. I've done some research with other charting frameworks that are more common with SAP (Vizframe), but they are limiting in its supported features (ex: vizframe doesn't support a regression line).

I cannot find an easy way to integrate a d3 chart into a SAPUI5 control. Can anyone provide some guidance on how this can be accomplished? Examples help!

Here's the chart I'm trying to implement:

https://bl.ocks.org/ctufts/298bfe4b11989960eeeecc9394e9f118

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to implement your own custom control based on D3. Library is already available at the SAPUI5 resources here;

```
jQuery.sap.require("sap/ui/thirdparty/d3");
```

Some examples;

http://jsbin.com/zutamig/edit

http://jsbin.com/hacuw/1/edit?html,output

https://blogs.sap.com/2014/07/17/custom-sapui5-visualization-controls-with-d3js/

Chart library based on ChartJS, if you want to check;

https://github.com/SAP/openui5-charting-custom-controls

Developing Custom Controls;

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3Qkev2yk9w
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nw8SnXZFqrs

Building Custom Controls to Visualize Data;

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cY-WCWC1qxE

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I'm aware of the d3 library that is available within SAP UI5. I've seen some of these examples but they aren't all clear. Let me give custom controls a try!